# Link to Sitecore Media Item

Tags: sitecore

In one of my templates, I created a field named UploadedSitecoreFile and set the type to File.
I did this so that when a user creates a new item, they can browse the Media Library and select the PDF that they want to link to.

In my code-behind, I have the following:

```
Dim subItem = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, Item)
ltResourceInfoTag.Text = ltResourceInfoTag.Text & "<a href='" & subItem("UploadedSitecoreFile").ToString & "'>" & subItem("Name").ToString & "</a>"
```

Can someone tell me the correct way to link to a media item?

Thanks,
C.R. Junk

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will want to look at leveraging the `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager` to get the URL to a media library item.

Before you get there, get the field from the item and cast it to a `FileField`. Once you have a `FileField` you can get access to the `MediaItem`.

Example (`C#` not `VB` sorry):

```
Item subItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
Sitecore.Data.Fields.FileField fileField = ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.FileField)subItem.Fields["UploadedSitecoreFile"]);

string url = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(fileField.MediaItem);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had been playing around with the Mediamanager earlier, but was having no luck.