# Get image src and alt attribute in Sitecore 6?

Tags: sitecore

I use the following to get, for instance, the header of the current page;

```
Header = Sitecore.Context.Item["Header"]
```

But how would i go about getting the src url of a image field?

```
PictureSrc = Sitecore.Context.Item["MyImage"]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will want to look at leveraging the Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager to get the URL to a media library item.

Before you get there, get the field from the item and cast it to a FileField. Once you have a FileField you can get access to the MediaItem.

```
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imgField = ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)item.Fields["MyImage"]);

string url = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem);
string altText = imgField.Alt;
```

[Link to Sitecore Media Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036843/link-to-sitecore-media-item)

Comment: How would i get the alt text for the image in the same go?